# What library use for dynamic svg bubble charts

Tags: javascript, svg, charts

does anybody know which library or plugin should be used to generate similar chart as is at the end of this website:

https://photoworld.com/how-big-is-snapchat/

it's the dynamically growing bubbles, which are draggable.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Looking at the `vendor.js` file, it looks like the are using `d3`

Comment: thanks Sean, that's it!

Answer (score 0):

A good source for web based graphs is always D3.js https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery  in your case this might be helpful: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269